# Blank array_rand() when sourcing random mp3 from directory

Tags: php, random, directory, mp3

This is in the body of my `index.php` in root dir of site and `localhost/sound/` contains a bunch of randomly named `mp3` files.

```
<?php
$files = glob("/sound/*.mp3");
$random = array_rand($files)
?>
<embed src="<?php echo $random ?>" 
width="140" height="40" autostart="true" loop="TRUE"> 
</embed>
```

When I view source of the page in browser it shows

```
<embed src="" 
width="140" height="40" autostart="true" loop="TRUE"> 
</embed>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that `glob` is actually returning matches:

```
$files = glob("/sound/*.mp3");
if (count($files) < 1)
  die('No files found');
$random = $files[array_rand($files)];

...
```

You could do the same thing, but provide a fallback default:

```
$files = glob("/sound/*.mp3");
$random = count($files) > 1 ? $files[array_rand($files)] : 'path/to/default.mp3';

...
```

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't seem to change anything, i tried using an mp3 in the same directory as the php file so i could use 'default.mp3'; but still nothing shows up and the viewed source is the same... what's going on? O.o

Comment: Do a `var_dump` on `$files`, what do you see?

Comment: sorry, how do i implement a var_dump?

Comment: `$files = glob("/sound/*.mp3");
var_dump($files); die();` - copy/paste the output to your question as an edit. (edit the argument in `glob` to use the correct path...)

Comment: thanks Chris! finally some progress - here's the output: array(2) { [0]=> string(24) "sound/lowyourchicken.mp3" [1]=> string(20) "sound/opencircle.mp3" }

Comment: OK, so we've established that the `glob` function is finding some MP3 files.  Now... what is array_rand giving you?  Move your var_dump/die combo down a few lines, and do a var_dump on `$random`.  What do you have there?

Comment: ah i've been too blind, sorry I managed to miss your change to the generation of $random when i was implementing your changes the first time (i just used your if/die combo and the fallback), when I did what you said it returned int[0] and then I tried using your code instead of my original and got my integer back. it works perfectly! Many many thanks dude.

Comment: Good deal, glad we could help!

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure you are actually getting some file names back. Note that `glob()` expects a path on your filesystem. The path `/sound/*.mp3` should probably be something like `sound/*.mp3` (i.e. relative to your PHP script) or `/var/www/html/sound/*.mp3` (an absolute path to where your web files are stored).

You should put a check in your code to verify that you're getting files back. For example:

```
if ($files === FALSE || count($files) == 0)
{
    die('No MP3s!');
}
```

Second, `array_rand()` returns a random array key. You'll have to look up that key in the array to retrieve the corresponding value:

```
<embed src="<?php echo $files[$random] ?>"
```

Comment: thanks for the advice re the path, i've removed the first / in there (it is relative to the php file but i don't know the absolute path as it's hosted not a server - i think it's a centos virtual server (can you use URLs?)

i've tried both of your suggestions, but the end result is always the same. No MP3s should be printed on the page if there are none found right? cos it's not being, and the viewed source is the same...